# Custom threads in serlvets and servlet lifecycle

Tags: multithreading, servlets, spring-mvc

Say I start a thread(not daemon) of my own in a servlet(can be a controller in springMVC app or a struts action controller):

1. Let us assume that the action is done with it's processing and wants to push the response out. Will this happen even though the thread I started is still running? Basically what I want to know is will the container wait till the thread is done with it's work to push the response out?
2. Assuming in the above, the container does not wait for the thread to push response out, will it wait till the background thread is done to reap the servlet thread spawned to handle this particular request or it will reap this thread only when the custom thread is done with it's work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom thread spawned by a servlet thread is no different than any other thread: it's an independant, parallel flow of execution. The servlet thread doesn't care about the custom spawned thread: it continues its execution.

So the response will be sent to the browser as if no custom thread had been spawned, and whether the custom spawned thread is still running or not is irrelevant.

Once the servlet thread has finished serving the request and sending the response, it goes back to the pool and can start serving another request. Once again, whether a custom thread has been spawned, and whether this custom thread is still running, are irrelevant.